# Global Navigation onclick get the name

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

Trying to add  Global Navigation is the list of navigation links, On click of link want to get the name/ id for the selected list.

I'm getting `undefined`, Can you please help me on this.

```
selectedValues(event) {
    // alert(event.detail.label);
    // alert(event.target.dataset.id);
    // alert(event.target.value);
    alert(event.target.dataset.menuItemId);
    alert(event.target.name);
  }
```

```
<nav class="slds-context-bar__secondary" role="navigation" onclick={selectedValues}>
                            <ul class="slds-grid">
                                <li class="slds-context-bar__item" data-menu-item-id="Dashboard" data-id="Dashboard">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-context-bar__label-action"
                                        title="Dashboard" name="Dashboard" data-id="Dashboard" label="Dashboard">
                                        <span class="slds-truncate" title="Dashboard">Dashboard</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="slds-context-bar__item ">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-context-bar__label-action"
                                        title="Timesheet" name="Timesheet" label="Timesheet">
                                        <span class="slds-truncate" title="Timesheet">Timesheet</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="slds-context-bar__item ">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-context-bar__label-action"
                                        title="Invoices" name="Invoices" label="Invoices">
                                        <span class="slds-truncate" title="Invoices">Invoices</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
onDashboardClick(event) {
    const dashboard = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-id");
}
```

```
  <nav class="slds-context-bar__secondary" role="navigation" >
    <ul class="slds-grid">
        <li class="slds-context-bar__item" data-menu-item-id="Dashboard" data-id="Dashboard" onclick={onDashboardClick}>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-context-bar__label-action"
                    title="Dashboard" name="Dashboard" data-id="Dashboard" label="Dashboard">
                <span class="slds-truncate" title="Dashboard">Dashboard</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```